# Different packages executing "dotnet lambda package" on Windows environment versus an Ubuntu environment

Tags: c#, ubuntu, aws-lambda, bamboo, aws-cli

So, I've been working on getting a Bamboo CI server up and running in an EC2 instance in AWS. Everything has been chugging along nicely; however, I've run in to one hell of an issue.  The CI part works fine, but it seems that the artifact developed by executing "dotnet lambda publish" on my Ubuntu-based Bamboo server is creating an incompatible package compared to executing "dotnet lambda publish" on my Windows machine.  When I deploy the package generated by my Bamboo server, I simply get the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "LambdaException",
  "errorMessage": "Unable to load assembly '<project-name>, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."
}
```

I've looked into the contents of the package and although there are no visible differences in the files; there is some difference in the file size.  The package generated on Ubuntu is approximately 14.8 MB, while the package generated on Windows is approximately 15.4 MB.

Can anyone possibly explain the difference between these package processes?  Why might I be getting a smaller package when compiling against Ubuntu? Why does my Windows package happen to work while the Ubuntu package complains about a file not found?

I had assumed that the "dotnet lambda package" command would specifically tool the build for the Lambda context regardless of the operating system environment.  To create different and seemingly incompatible builds in different environments with the same CLI command seems strange.

---

Edit: Upon further investigation, I believe it has something to do with the zipping process that is used on the Bamboo CI Server via the execution of the "dotnet lambda package" cli.  When I bring it locally to my Windows machine and attempt to upload the package again, it fails.  After a little bit more investigation, I found that if I unzip the package on Windows and then re-zip it via right clicking and going send to -> compressed (zipped) folder, then upload it again, the exact same file contents will start working.  Perhaps it's an issue with the zip execution during the "dotnet lambda package" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the realization about my edit, I decided to get in touch with the guys over at Amazon who helped create the Amazon.Lambda.Tools package.  It turns out that if you don't have "zip" installed on your linux machine, it will automatically assume that you're running a Windows machine and it will choose the incorrect executable to zip the final package created with "dotnet lambda package".  When it uses the incorrect executable, the chmod commands applied aren't carried over.

Simple fix, execute: apt install zip

This will ensure that your Ubuntu box uses the correct zip executable and the resulting zip file can be uploaded to Lambda without issue.

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/100

Comment: Seriously, this need to be in AWS document somewhere~

Comment: Right though!? Glad my hours of pain helped save someone else some time!